# How can I run bash without running initialization/configuration scripts?

Tags: bash

I have `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile` and similar files under system directories.

How can I run bash  without running the initialization/configuration scripts

- under `~`?
- under system directories?
- under both above?

Requirements

- don't change the files.
- run bash as a login or nonlogin shell (interested in both). I still allow running those files when starting Linux.
- run bash as a interactive or noninteractive shell (interested in both)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bash --noprofile
```

runs a Bash shell without loading any of the config scripts (both user and system-wide).

From `man bash`:

```
   -i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
   -l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).

(...)

   --noprofile
          Do  not  read  either  the  system-wide  startup  file  /etc/profile  or  any  of  the  personal initialization files ~/.bash_profile,
          ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile.  By default, bash reads these files when it is invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).
```